# If we cannot have constructor within java interface, then what is this?

Tags: java

This is the code.

```
public interface AppointmentDAO {
    public Integer addAppointment(Appointment appointment);
    public Integer updateAppointment(Appointment appointment);
    public Integer deleteAppointment(Integer id);
    public Appointment getAppointmentById(Integer id);
    public ResultSet getAllAppointments();
}
```

Aren't all these constructors within interface?

Comment: No. Those are all methods within an interface. A constructor would be `public AppointmentDAO()` notice that it has the same name as the class it is in **and** no return type.

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry, I'm actually new to java.

Answer (score 0):

These are not Constructors, these are just methods. The Constructors don't have returns.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying. Sorry, I'm actually new to java.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not.

A constructor is similar to a method but in actual, it is not a method.

A Java method and Java constructor can be differentiated by its name and return type. A constructor has the same name as that of class and it does not return any value. For example,

```
class Example {

   Example() {
     // constructor body
   }
}
```

Here, Example() is a constructor. It has the same name as that of the class and doesn't have a return type.

```
class Example {
    void Example() {
    // method body
   }
}
```

Here, Example() has the same name as that of the class. However, it has a return type void. Hence, it's a method, not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are to create instance of Class, It has same name as class name like below:

```
Class A {
  public A() {}
}
```

Whereas Interface has just abstract methods with different names

```
Interface B {
 public void test(); 
}
```